# Xcode 11 crashes every time when using canvas with Hello World project

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

I just installed Xcode 11 form the AppStore and created a SwiftUI project. When trying to view the ContentView in canvas, Xcode crashes every time

I tried cleanup and removing DerivedData, creating different views and different projects without success

```
Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 11A420a

Dyld Error Message:
  Symbol not found: _$s7SwiftUI7BindingV13dynamicMemberACyqd__Gs15WritableKeyPathCyxqd__G_tcluig
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/UVKit.framework/UVKit
  Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Versions/A/SwiftUI

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   dyld                            0x000000011043b44e __abort_with_payload + 10
1   dyld                            0x000000011046499e abort_with_payload_wrapper_internal + 80
2   dyld                            0x00000001104649d0 abort_with_payload + 9
3   dyld                            0x00000001104621b3 dyld::halt(char const*) + 463
4   dyld                            0x00000001103eca02 dyld::fastBindLazySymbol(ImageLoader**, unsigned long) + 140
5   libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff6c59d29e dyld_stub_binder + 282
6   ???                             0x0000000131da48e8 OBJC_CLASS_$__TtCV5UVKit19DiagnosticsPullDown10MenuTarget + 120
7   com.apple.dt.UVKit              0x0000000131ceb3d9 protocol witness for View.body.getter in conformance InsetEditor + 9
8   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff4259da39 ViewBody.apply(_:) + 585
9   com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff4259ec29 protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update(_:graph:attribute:) in conformance ViewBody<A> + 137
10  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490ec259 partial apply + 25
11  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d55a7 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 1111
12  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d5865 AG::Graph::update_attribute(unsigned int, bool) + 377
13  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d8e6f AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(unsigned int, unsigned int, AGTypeID, bool*) + 199
14  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff425f32b9 LayoutTraitsProxy.layoutTraits() + 41
15  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5d8e3 accumulateSpacing #1 (ofChild:) in StackLayout.Header.init(layoutContext:proxies:majorAxis:minorAxisAlignment:uniformSpacing:childStorage:capacity:) + 563
16  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5cd25 StackLayout.Header.init(layoutContext:proxies:majorAxis:minorAxisAlignment:uniformSpacing:childStorage:capacity:) + 805
17  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5d62d specialized ManagedBufferPointer.init(bufferClass:minimumCapacity:makingHeaderWith:) + 349
18  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5fc29 specialized closure #2 in HVStack.updateOutput<A>(attributeContext:layoutContext:children:) + 329
19  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a6208a partial apply for specialized  + 42
20  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff426a8367 specialized static LayoutComputerDelegate.update<A>(_:maybeInPlace:create:) + 247
21  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff426b6290 specialized static LayoutComputerDelegate.update<A>(_:maybeInPlace:create:) + 16
22  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5ac8c specialized HVStack.updateOutput<A>(attributeContext:layoutContext:children:) + 220
23  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5acf0 specialized HVStack.updateOutput<A>(attributeContext:layoutContext:children:) + 48
24  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff4281a9f6 specialized LayoutQuery<>.update(context:) + 358
25  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff4293c7ea partial apply for protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update(_:graph:attribute:) in conformance DynamicLayoutViewChildGeometry + 26
26  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d55a7 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 1111
27  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d5865 AG::Graph::update_attribute(unsigned int, bool) + 377
28  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d8e6f AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(unsigned int, unsigned int, AGTypeID, bool*) + 199
29  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff425f32b9 LayoutTraitsProxy.layoutTraits() + 41
30  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5d8e3 accumulateSpacing #1 (ofChild:) in StackLayout.Header.init(layoutContext:proxies:majorAxis:minorAxisAlignment:uniformSpacing:childStorage:capacity:) + 563
31  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5cd25 StackLayout.Header.init(layoutContext:proxies:majorAxis:minorAxisAlignment:uniformSpacing:childStorage:capacity:) + 805
32  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5d62d specialized ManagedBufferPointer.init(bufferClass:minimumCapacity:makingHeaderWith:) + 349
33  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5fc29 specialized closure #2 in HVStack.updateOutput<A>(attributeContext:layoutContext:children:) + 329
34  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a6208a partial apply for specialized  + 42
35  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff426a8367 specialized static LayoutComputerDelegate.update<A>(_:maybeInPlace:create:) + 247
36  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff426b6290 specialized static LayoutComputerDelegate.update<A>(_:maybeInPlace:create:) + 16
37  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5ac8c specialized HVStack.updateOutput<A>(attributeContext:layoutContext:children:) + 220
38  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5acf0 specialized HVStack.updateOutput<A>(attributeContext:layoutContext:children:) + 48
39  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff4281a9f6 specialized LayoutQuery<>.update(context:) + 358
40  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff4293c7ea partial apply for protocol witness for static UntypedAttribute._update(_:graph:attribute:) in conformance DynamicLayoutViewChildGeometry + 26
41  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d55a7 AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 1111
42  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d5865 AG::Graph::update_attribute(unsigned int, bool) + 377
43  com.apple.AttributeGraph        0x00007fff490d8e6f AG::Graph::input_value_ref_slow(unsigned int, unsigned int, AGTypeID, bool*) + 199
44  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff425f32b9 LayoutTraitsProxy.layoutTraits() + 41
45  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5d8e3 accumulateSpacing #1 (ofChild:) in StackLayout.Header.init(layoutContext:proxies:majorAxis:minorAxisAlignment:uniformSpacing:childStorage:capacity:) + 563
46  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5cd25 StackLayout.Header.init(layoutContext:proxies:majorAxis:minorAxisAlignment:uniformSpacing:childStorage:capacity:) + 805
47  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5d62d specialized ManagedBufferPointer.init(bufferClass:minimumCapacity:makingHeaderWith:) + 349
48  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a5fc29 specialized closure #2 in HVStack.updateOutput<A>(attributeContext:layoutContext:children:) + 329
49  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff42a6208a partial apply for specialized  + 42
50  com.apple.SwiftUI               0x00007fff426a8367 specialized static
```

Is there anything I can do?

**EDIT**: ContentView code generated when creating a brand new project:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your import statements and then show some code for the initial ContentView. Also try making a brand new SwiftUI project, change nothing and run that. If it works then look for the error in your code. BTW - Sometimes the compilation takes a while and you just have to wait.

Comment: It is a brand new project, I'll attach the code, but it is the standard one. I have no errors shown by Xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The preview canvas does not work on Mojave, only Catalina. The current version of Catalina is Beta 9. I'd expect things to not work on Mojave. If on Mojave you can still see the effect of SwiftUI when you use a playground or run on a device.

Comment: I'm on Catalina, but on Beta 8. Probably this is the problem, thanks!